# NotCoordinatorException is being received on kafka streams instance side repeatedly

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are using Kafka version : 0.10.2.0
and kafka streams version is 1.1.0
On the kafka broker machine which the consumer is thinking is Group Coordinator we see following log line ::

```
2018-08-18 11:54:12,693 [kafka-request-handler-5] TRACE (Logging.scala:36) - [KafkaApi-48476987] Sending join group response {error_code=16,generation_id=0,group_protocol=,leader_id=,member_id=,members=[]} for correlation id 538 to client chitraguptaV1-dcf33a6c-368e-472e-aee7-120f1216aa3f-StreamThread-2-consumer.
```

And since NotCoordinatorException is retriable exception, it is being continuously retried, and group coordinator is continuously sending same error code(error_code=16) to consumer client

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/AbstractCoordinator.java#L380

We are seeing following log lines on kafka streams instance side

```
Discovered group coordinator <groupcoordinator_host_name>:9092 (id: 2099006660 rack: null)
(Re-)joining group
Group coordinator <groupcoordinator_host_name>:9092 (id: 2099006660 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
InitiateJoinGroup request failed This is not the correct coordinator.
```

Please help us on fixing this.

Our Kafka cluster configuration:

```
delete.topic.enable:        true
auto.create.topics.enable:      true
unclean.leader.election.enable:     false
controlled.shutdown.enable:     true
controlled.shutdown.max.retries:        3
controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms:       5000
default.replication.factor:     1
offsets.topic.num.partitions:       200
offsets.topic.replication.factor:       3
offsets.retention.check.interval.ms:        600000
offsets.commit.timeout.ms:      5000
num.network.threads:        3
num.replica.fetchers:       2
num.io.threads:     8
socket.send.buffer.bytes:       8388608
socket.receive.buffer.bytes:        8388608
socket.request.max.bytes:       314572800
log.retention.hours:        4
log.retention.bytes:        10737418240
log.segment.bytes:      536870912
log.cleanup.policy:     delete
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms:        6000
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms:       6000
zookeeper.sync.time.ms:     2000
queued.max.requests:        500
replica.lag.time.max:       10000
replica.fetch.wait.max.ms:      500
min.insync.replicas:        2
replica.fetch.max.bytes:        67108864
message.max.bytes:      67108864
replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms:      5000
replica.socket.timeout.ms:      30000
replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes:        65536
```

Our Kafka Streams side configuration:

```
props.setProperty(StreamsConfig.NUM_STANDBY_REPLICAS_CONFIG, "1");
props.setProperty(StreamsConfig.STATE_CLEANUP_DELAY_MS_CONFIG, "1800000");
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, WallclockTimestampExtractor.class.getName());
props.put(StreamsConfig.ROCKSDB_CONFIG_SETTER_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomRocksDBConfig.class);
props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, "3");
props.put(StreamsConfig.REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG, "2");
props.put(StreamsConfig.TOPIC_PREFIX + TopicConfig.CLEANUP_POLICY_CONFIG, TopicConfig.CLEANUP_POLICY_DELETE);
props.put(StreamsConfig.TOPIC_PREFIX + TopicConfig.RETENTION_MS_CONFIG, "43200000");
props.put(StreamsConfig.TOPIC_PREFIX + TopicConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "lz4");
props.put(StreamsConfig.CONSUMER_PREFIX + ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "240000");
props.put(StreamsConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "300000");
props.put(StreamsConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "20");
props.put(StreamsConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, "2400");
props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, "1048576");
props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, "2400");
props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, "300000");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
```

Comment: it seems something wrong in your kafka config

Comment: You probably want to remove your employer from the hostnames... That said, you need to verify the consumer offsets topic is healthy and validate your brokers can all talk to each other first. If the wrong coordinator is being sent join group requests, some metadata is out of date and these two things are the most likely causes.